# blackberry JDE 4.7 - TouchEvent Class - difference between getX and getGlobalX

Tags: blackberry, eclipse-plugin, touchscreen, rim-4.7

In the blackberry JDE 4.7,

under the TouchEvent, there are two similar sounding methods:

- getX(int touch) "return mapped x coordinate"
- getGlobalX(int touch) "return global x coordindate"

Does anyone know what the difference is between the two?  The javadocs talk about mapped vs global but I'm not sure what that means.

Any help poindexter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

getX is the position in your field (button, listfield) and getGlobalX the x-position in your screen.

Answer (score 0):

Like rAyt mentions.

The mapped coordinate is with respect to your current view or field.  The global coordinate is with respect to your screen.

This link may help you:
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/rim/board/message?board.id=java_dev&thread.id=36636